# python subprocess from 2.7 to 3.6

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to run a command line took called xfoil through python script. I wrote it in python 2.7 first but for later work, i need to rewrite it in 3.7. 
What I am doing is, passing bunch of string commands to the cli tool xfoil by writing in to the sdtin. This works fine with python 2.7 but not with 3.6. I get a exit code 0 in both, so I can not debug either.

here is the code I am using,

```
import subprocess as sp
#import os
import shutil
import sys
import string


"""
class Popen(args, bufsize=0, executable=None,
            stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
            preexec_fn=None, close_fds=False, shell=False,
            cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False,
            startupinfo=None, creationflags=0):
"""
xfoilpath = r'/usr/bin/xfoil'
ps = sp.Popen(xfoilpath,
              stdin=sp.PIPE,
              stdout=sp.PIPE,
              stderr=None,
              universal_newlines=True, shell=True)

def cmd(cmd):
    ps.stdin.write(cmd+'\n')
    #ps.stdin.write(bytes(cmd+'\n', 'utf-8'))
'''
out, err = ps.communicate(input="naca 4512")
print (out)
print (err)
#print (ps.poll())
'''
cmd("naca 4512")
cmd("pane")
cmd("oper")
cmd("visc 5e005")
cmd("M 0.2")
cmd("ITER")
cmd("200")
cmd("pacc")
cmd("4512.log")
cmd(" ")
cmd("aseq 0.0 0.0 1.0")
cmd(" ")  # escape OPER
cmd("quit")  # exit
# resp = ps.stdout.read()
# print "resp:",resp   # console ouput for debug
ps.stdout.close()
ps.stdin.close()
ps.wait()
```

I have tried all combination of arguments with popen(), but can not figure out why it is not working. Any suggestion on how to debug will be very helpful.

Comment: just figured out that it works with popen.communicate() funtion.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question and accept it. Maybe it will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

just figured out, it works fine with popen.communicate() in python3.6. but I wonder it should also work by writing into the stdin. It will be interesting to know what is missing. The new code which works in as follows,

```
out, err = ps.communicate("naca 4512\n"
                      "pane\n"
                      "oper\n"
                      "visc 5e005\n"
                      "M 0.2\n"
                      "ITER\n"
                      "200\n"
                      "pacc\n"
                      "4512.log\n"
                      " \n"
                      "aseq 0 0 1\n"
                      " \n"
                      "quit\n")
```